# Unable to find login() function location in opencart

Tags: authentication, opencart

private function validate() {
        if (!$this->user->login(@$this->request->post['username'], @$this->request->post['password'])) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_login');
        }

```
    if (!$this->error) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Here after this function is called($this->user->login()) i wanted to know where the function is located.

Comment: I have two modules user and admin .I wanted to know location of login() function so that i can modify validation process.

Answer (score 1):

#### For the admin part:

`$this->user` represents a user of the admin area, it's an instance of class `User` located in the file `<OC_ROOT>/system/library/user.php`

#### For the catalog part:

There is no such a member named `$this->user`, but there is a member named `$this->customer` which represents a user of the system catalog (a customer) and it's an instance of class `Customer` located in the file `<OC_ROOT>/system/library/customer.php`

Comment: Thanks so much this helped lot as iam new to opencart.

Comment: u r welcomed at any time, don't hesitate to ask about any other part

Comment: @SantoshNyamagoudar BTW, read [this tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru), it's very good for beginners

Comment: For newer versions of opencart, they moved the user and customer files to <OC_ROOT>/system/library/cart/user.php. (Thanks to windows search. ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Opencart version 3:

This model file responsible for admin login is located in:

```
<ROOT>/system/library/cart/user.php
```